# Why does Typescript not like it when I use a simple object for an interface that has all optional props?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to provide a mock for uirouter's StateService...  I am simply doing:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  stateService = jasmine.createSpyObj('StateService', ['go']) as StateService;
}

...

it('calls go', () => {
  // ...
  let options = { location: 'replace', inherit: true };
  expect(stateService.go).toHaveBeenCalledWith('foo', params, options);
});
```

I get:

> error TS2345: Argument of type '{ location: string; inherit: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Expected'.
> Type '{ location: string; inherit: boolean; }' is not assignable to type '{ location?: ExpectedRecursive<boolean | "replace">; relative?: ExpectedRecursive<string | StateObject | StateDeclaration>; ... 8 more ...; source?: ExpectedRecursive<...>; }'.
> Types of property 'location' are incompatible.
> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ExpectedRecursive<boolean | "replace">'.
> expect(stateService.go).toHaveBeenCalledWith('foo', params, options);

Yet if I do it all inline without a variable assignment:

```
it('calls go', () => {
  // ...
  expect(stateService.go).toHaveBeenCalledWith('foo', params, { location: 'replace', inherit: true });
});
```

Then it works fine...

uirouter's TransitionOptions interface is defined like:

```
export interface TransitionOptions {
    location?: boolean | 'replace';
    relative?: string | StateDeclaration | StateObject;
    inherit?: boolean;
    notify?: boolean;
    reload?: boolean | string | StateDeclaration | StateObject;
    custom?: any;
    supercede?: boolean;
    reloadState?: StateObject;
    redirectedFrom?: Transition;
    current?: () => Transition;
    source?: 'sref' | 'url' | 'redirect' | 'otherwise' | 'unknown';
}
```

Where everything is optional...  Why does Typescript not like me assigning this to a simple object as a variable?

Comment: Why do you declare `options` if you don't even use it?

Comment: @EduMüller sorry that was a copy/paste error.. I edited and fixed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's distil this to a simpler example with the same error.

```
function foo(v: "replace") {
}

foo("replace"); // This works

const t1 = "replace";
foo(t1); // This also works

let t2 = "replace";
foo(t2);  // Compiler error 

let t3:"replace" = "replace";
foo(t3); // This works
```

If you declare a variable and assign it a string value, typescript will assume it is of type `string`, not a string literal type.

Applying it to your `options` example

```
let options1 = { 
    location: 'replace',  // This is a mutable string, not a string literal!
    inherit: true 
};

foo(options1.location); // << compiler error

let options2: {location:'replace', inherit: boolean} = { 
    location: 'replace', // String literal, because we declared the type
    inherit: true 
};

foo(options2.location); // << This works!
```

You've stumbled upon interesting behaviour with regard to typescript choosing between a string type and a string literal type. Here's some more interesting cases.

```
function foo(v: "replace") {
}

function bar(p: {location: 'replace'}) {
}

let options = {
    location: 'replace'
}

bar(options); // Compilation error
foo(options.location); // Also a compilation error

bar({ location: 'replace'}); // No error.

foo( { location: 'replace'}.location); // But the compiler calls this an error! (I don't think it should)
```

Answer (score 3):

The type of this line:

```
let options = { location: 'replace', inherit: true };
```

is

```
options: { location: string, boolean: true }
```

This is because the type of `'replace'` is expanded to `string`. Because of this, `string` is too wide to assign to `location` which is expected to be `'replace' | boolean | undefined`.

To tell Typescript that `'replace'` is not a `string` and should only be `replace`, use `as const`.

```
let options = { location: 'replace' as const, inherit: true };
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because when you declare by inferring the type of the variable from the assigned value, it will generalize the value of the `location` property to `string`, making it invalid for the `replace` value, as `replace` will just be the property value, not its type.

To fix this you can infer the type of the variable in the declaration, like this:

```ts
function foo(param: TransitionOptions) {
    console.log('foo', param)
}

foo({ location: 'replace', inherit: true })

let bar: TransitionOptions = { location: 'replace', inherit: true }
foo(bar)
```

Comment: Yeah I figured I could do that, but didn't want to go through the annoyingness of having to import `TransitionOptions` from uirouter.